# Where does C store '\0'?

Tags: c

The below code reads a line and return the line length. lim is the length of the array s[].

When the input line length is lim, then s[lim] = '\0'. But the array s[] is only lim-length long, from s[0] to s[lim-1]. Will it cause an buffer overflow? I tested it many times, but the code seemed to work just fine.

```
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{ 
    int c, i;

    for(i = 0; i < lim-1 && ( c = getchar())!=  EOF && c!= '\n'; i++)
           s[i] = c;
    if( c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
```

}

Comment: At `i == lim-1` `\n` will store.

Comment: The last value of `i` for which the loop will read a character is `lim - 2`. If the loop stops at `lim-1`, then `c` can't be `'\n'`, so `s[lim]` will never be accessed. If the loop hits `c=='\n'`, then `i` can be at most `lim-2`, so writing `'\n'` and `'\0'` still won't overflow. That said, this doesn't mean the code does what you think or what you want.

Answer (score 5):

The `'\0'` is just another character.  It is stored right after the last character of the string.

Often, you can "get away" with writing off the end of a buffer with no obvious harm, but don't do it.  It's a bug.

I once had to debug a program that contained an error like this.  The program was writing a single byte past the end of one buffer.  In the debug build, there was enough extra stuff on the stack that the single byte extra caused no harm; the crash only occurred in the release build, but the debugger didn't really work since it was the non-debug build.  This is an example of why it is good to test your code both in a "debug" build and in a release build (compiled the way you would give it to your users).

Comment: Note that this code does not actually overflow. It will read at most `lim-1` characters, and then the `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example as to how to clearly define an interface - its input and returned value;

" int getline(char s[], int lim) "

One possible definition of "lim" is, maximum number of characters to be copied to s[], excluding the terminating null-character i.e. '\0'
Example: 
char arr[] = "hello";
getline(arr, strlen(arr));

The other definition of "lim" is, Maximum number of characters to be copied into s[] (including the terminating null-character)
Example:
char arr[] = "hello";
getline(arr, sizeof(arr));

You seem to be supposing the 2nd definition of "lim".

Answer (score 0):

This is a function straight out of "The C Programming Language" by K&R. It's from chapter one. It works because it is correct.

Consider "cat". This is a four character array {'c','a','t','\0'}. The length of the string is 3.
If s[]="cat" then s[0]='c', s[3]='\0'. Eh?

The string length returned by srtlen or what have you is the number of characters minus one. The array is allocated to hold all the 4 characters. That's where the '\0' is, at the end of the array.

Comment: The question is 'Where does C store `\0`'. This answer has no bearing whatsoever on the question.

Comment: The strlen is the number of characters minus one. The '\0' is stored as the fourth element of the array...

Comment: It is usual practice in C for a function that operates on a buffer to receive two arguments: a pointer to the buffer, and the size of the buffer (maximum safe length).  It is not usual practice for functions to assume that they can write one position past the specified size of the buffer.  In other words, it would be very surprising if `lim` actually meant "the size of the buffer, minus one to leave you room for a terminating null byte".

Comment: It doesn't, it's set equal to 1000. See "The C Programming Language" Section 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause buffer overflow. In fact, a '\0' indicates a NULL position, which is considered as the end of an array. When you go from the beginning to the end of an array, the last position containing the '\0' character will never be considered as a position containing valid data.

You could go over all the array by using while(index < size) as a condition, or by using while(array[position] != NULL)